# Kernel not upgrading

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I have upgraded to 22.04LTS and the kernel stays the same at 5.14.0-1033-oem

I want to get 5.17 , and I tried a manual install, everything installs, i reboot, update, and I am still on my old kernel

I believe 22.04 just shipped with 5.15, but even after upgrading my disto, i am still on 5.14

Anyone know why my kernel will not upgrade?

Comment: You're using an OEM kernel, that's why.

Comment: Do you know how to just use a normal kernal? and not the oem one?

Comment: If you're using an OEM kernel you probably have a reason for that, typically hardware support for specific manufacturers. I suggest you keep it for the time being.

Comment: Great Thanks.It is for a lenovo X1 Carbon. I have heard of others upgrading to 5.17 without issue. But I have no idea what is stopping me from upgrading from the oem to a generic

Comment: 5.17 is not an "official" kernel version for 22.04 (yet). The hardware support given by the OEM 5.14 may not (actually almost certainly not) have been yet added to the current 5.15 branch and that's why it's being kept for the moment. In due time it may upgrade to newer branches. The point being the system "knows" what it's doing.

Comment: Do you have specific reasons to want to upgrade to 5.17? If not, stay off of this if your system is functioning well with the manufacturer's provided kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where a system upgrade did not install the latest released kernel (i.e., the system had 5.4.0-87-generic instead of a 5.15.0 kernel). Running `apt install linux-image-generic` installed the latest LTS kernel.

Comment: Read the comments on the question. Custom OEM kernel what you purpose is not a good idea and may mess up the system.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command in terminal to remove the current kernel from your system, which should automatically downgrade you to the next most recent version.

$ sudo apt remove linux-image-$(uname -r) linux-headers-$(uname -r)
You will need to reboot your system after the downgrade, in order to start utilizing the other kernel.